# Java SQL-Derby column not found?

Tags: java, database, exception, derby

I'm working on a very simple Java - Derby database. 
For some reason, i get one exception: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'address' not found.

I only have two columns:
1) name
2) address

Then i try to read from the database, but then the exception happens.
I tried to delete the local derby file, then rebuild the code.. didn't work.

Here is the critical part of the code:

```
try
        {
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "USERS", null);
            if (!rs.next())
            {
                createStatement.execute("create table users(name varchar(20), address varchar(20))");
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("Hiba a table letrehozasanal");
        }
```

Then i got two more methods one for adding the user and one for reading the users.

```
public void addUser(String name, String address)
    {
        try 
        {
            String sql = "insert into users values (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setString(2, address);
            pstmt.execute();
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("Hiba user hozzaadasnal");
        }
    }

    public void showAllUsers()
    {
        String sql = "select * from users";
        try {
            ResultSet rs = createStatement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                System.out.println(name + "\n" + address);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
            System.out.println("Hiba a kiolvasasnal");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `create table` statement is conditional. Maybe there is already a `users` table in the database, and it has a different table definition? Try accessing your database using an interactive SQL tool like Derby's `ij` or SquirellSQL and see what actual tables are present.

Comment: But i deleted the database, then rebuilded the database! So there shouldn't be an existing users table. I have to keep digging..